# Azure SQL: How to determine if table was altered or created and by whom

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

My team works with a large Azure SQL database where several other teams insert and read data from our database. They sometimes need to create or alter tables but those actions should be coordinated with our team and unfortunately has not been the case. We've had a couple scenario's where one of those teams updated a stored procedure. As a result their changes are not under our source control and if we create a local database for development or do a backup/restore we get errors because of missing references.

We are looking for a way to programmatically determine if a table was altered or modified. It doesn't need to be real-time. I considered reading logs and looking for alter or create commands. I've not has much success as the logs are binary and I don't currently know how to parse them. My other thought is to keep a copy of the master database sys tables and routinely compare them to see if something changed. I'm not sure how well that would work or if I could determine who made the change. Thoughts, Ideas?

Please keep in mind that this is using an Azure SQL Database which is a bit more limited than a standard SQL database.

Comment: Why not just give them credentials to query the db and not full admin rights?

Comment: Of course, but they do need to make changes occasionally and we are all professionals. It would be better for us to react to the rare unauthorized change than to remove permissions from the other teams. It's also currently not within my scope to remove permissions.

Comment: You can run the schema compare through a process which report the current schema vs what you have in your source control?

Comment: That's how we currently fix the problem. We are looking for a solution that would identify that a change was made and who made the change so that we can properly train them, also hoping to create an automated process to notify us when we have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DDL Triggers as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017).

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE   
AS   
   PRINT 'Save change on a log'   
   SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

Additionally you can use Extended Events to track schema changes. Look at samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-xevent-db-diff-from-svr#code-samples).

Finally you can also see how [Azure SQL Auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing#subheading-1) may fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I've been occupied for the past couple days. I'll give this a shot and see how it works. I've reviewed the Azure SQL Auditing and it's not very impressive but this trigger looks interesting.

Comment: The extended events looks like it would work as well but I created a trigger based on the code you provided. I have it writing to the eventlog along with the current sqluser and hostname. It's working nicely.

Comment: That's great news. Thank you for letting us know.